# AngularJS promises without callback?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, asynchronous, angular-promise

Usually when I'm getting some data async way I would do it like

```
var promise = $http.get('/api/v1/movies/avengers');

promise.then(
  function(payload) {
    $scope.movieContent = payload;
  });
```

In fact the scenario is very common - I send some request and when it's ready, I assing EVERYTHING it returns to some variable/prop. But everytime it require to make callback even if the callback is always the same.

Is there any way to do it like

```
$scope.movieContent = $http.get('/api/v1/movies/avengers'); //updates to real value when request is done
```

or kind of

```
updateWhenReady($scope.movieContent , '/api/v1/movies/avengers');
```

It's not big deal but when used a lot makes difference in my opinion.

Comment: nope. javascript doesn't have that.

Comment: its very easy to write a service to do that

Comment: ngResource does exactly that.

Comment: Auto-promise unwrapping feature used to be available with http promise earlier. Later it got deprecated (1.2.x) and you could only turn it off by doing `.config(function ($parseProvider) {
    $parseProvider.unwrapPromises(true);
});`. With the newer version this feature is completely removed. Try your luch with the version of angular you are using. [See here for more details](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/fa6e411da26824a5bae55f37ce7dbb859653276d). However right way would be to chain through the promise itself. Another way is to use resolve in your route.

Answer (score 1):

You can design your service so that it returns an empty reference and populates itself when the service call returns successfully.  Use `angular.copy` to preserve the reference:

**Service**

```
app.factory('avengersService', function($http) {
   return  {
      getAvengers: function() {
         var avengers = [];
         avengers.$promise = $http.get('/api/v1/movies/avengers').then(function(result) {
             angular.copy(result.data, avengers);
             return result;
         });
         return avengers;
      }
   }
});
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, avengersService) {
    $scope.movieContent = avengersService.getAvengers();

    // or call the promise version
    avengersService.getAvengers().$promise.then(function(result) {
         $scope.movieContent = result.data;
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the async call in a function:

```
function load(cb, model){
        cb.then(function(payload){
            model = payload;
        });
    }
```

*But I would not recommend you doing this. Often, you want to perform specific tasks in the callback function (like handling loading indicators, ...).

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you asked for, but you can generate these callbacks "on-the-fly":

```
function assignToScope(propName) {
    return function (data) { $scope[propName] = data; };
}

$http.get('/api/v1/movies/avengers').then(assignToScope('movieContent'));
```

or (if you like this syntax more):

```
function assignToScope(propName, promise) {
    promise.then(function (data) { $scope[propName] = data; });
}

assignToScope('movieContent', $http.get('/api/v1/movies/avengers'));
```

Please note that error handling is important. If the promise rejects, you probably want to notify the user.

Comment: Is this proper way of creating assingToScope function? Shouldn't I create factory or something like that with angular pattern?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know... I do not have that much experience with Angular, more with plain JS ;-)